# Are there faster techiniques or shortcut for MOD'ing large numbers using pow(x,y,n)

Tags: python, math, primes, prime-factoring

I created the following to find primes in numbers by using powers of two to increase the size of the number until the gcd of the original number and and a larger number mod of the powers of two up to as high as we need to go have a gcd answer greater than 1. What i'm looking for is if a mathematician knows of any tricks to make this technique faster as it could be quite useful for finding prime factors. Any indications as to why or why not a shortcut doesn't exist would be helpful

```
def search_for_prime(hm):
   for x in range(2,500):
       answer = gcd_mod_find(hm**x, hm)
       if answer != 1:
           break
   return answer

def gcd_mod_find(hm, find):
    prevcr = hm
    getcr =  hm%(1<<(hm).bit_length()-1)
    bitlength = hm.bit_length()//2
    count=0
    found = False
    while getcr != 0 and getcr != 1 and bitlength > count:
       count+=1
       temp = hm%getcr
       prevcr = getcr
       getcr = temp
       answer = gcd(prevcr, find)
       if answer != 1:
          #print(f"{answer} found at {prevcr}")
          found = True
          break
    if found == True:
       return answer
    else:
       return 1
```

An example of how this works:

```
# Takes about less than a minute to find:
#  In [1677]: search_for_prime(1009732533765211)                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#  Out[1677]: 11344301

# Finds rather quickly that the number is prime:
# In [1679]: search_for_prime(10099)                                                                                                                                                                                                            
# Out[1679]: 10099

# Rather fast find of one of the primes
# In [1680]: search_for_prime(7919 * 7883)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# Out[1680]: 7919
```

My goal is for a mathematician to let me know if there are any optimizations to make this faster. I'm working on learning more about mod techniques (which lead me to a faster pollard_brent answers for large numbers rather than using random ints for y,c,m, which i'll share here for those who are interested ( This is to show that i could optimize pollard_brent, so hopefully a mathematician will know of tricks of how to optimize my method above:)

---

The following is a digression from the above question but useful for those interested in speed optimizations for finding factors using pollard_brent

Currently my method above is slower than a pollard brent optimization i made which is faster than it's (pollard_brent y,c,m as random) version ( So i made an optimization to make pollard_brent have consistently lower speed results that some might be interested in:

```
from sympy import isprime
from math import gcd


def pollard_brent_lars_opt(n):
    if n % 2 == 0: return 2
    if n % 3 == 0: return 3

    # This optimization is contributed by Lars Rocha. I use an equation instead of random numbers for significant
    # speed increases on larger numbers and consistent low speed results

    y,c,m = (1<<((n**2).bit_length()+1)), (1<<((n**2).bit_length())) , (1<<((n**2).bit_length()+1)) 

    #print(y,c,m)
    g, r, q = 1, 1, 1
    while g == 1:
        x = y
        for i in range(r):
            y = (pow(y, 2, n) + c) % n

        k = 0
        while k < r and g==1:
            ys = y
            for i in range(min(m, r-k)):
                y = (pow(y, 2, n) + c) % n
                q = q * abs(x-y) % n
            g = gcd(q, n)
            k += m
        r *= 2
    if g == n:
        while True:
            ys = (pow(ys, 2, n) + c) % n
            g = gcd(abs(x - ys), n)
            if g > 1:
                break

    return g

def get_factors_lars_opt(hm, offset=-2):
   num = hm
   vv = []
   while isprime(num // 1) != True:
     print(vv, num)
     a = find_prime_evens_lars_opt(num, offset)
     #print(a)
     if a[5] == 0:
       vv.append(a[1])
     elif a[5] == 2:
       if num % 2 == 0:
         vv.append(a[5])
       else:
         vv.append(a[3])
     elif a[5] == 3:
       if num % 2 == 0:
          vv.append(2)
       elif num % 3 == 0:
          vv.append(3)
       elif num % 5 == 0:
          vv.append(5)
       elif num % a[3] == 0:
          vv.append(a[3])
     else:
       vv.append(a[5])
     #print(a)
     num = num // vv[-1]
   if isprime(num):
     vv.append(num)
   print(vv)
   return vv


def find_prime_evens_lars_opt(hm, offset=-2): 
  y = 3 
  prevtemp = 3 
  if isprime(hm): 
     print(f"{hm} is already prime") 
     return hm 
  while True: 
    if y.bit_length() > hm.bit_length() -1: 
      prevtemp = pollard_brent_lars_opt(hm) 
      break 
    j = powers(hm, y) 
    temp = j 
    if j != 1 and j != 0: 
      temp = j 
      temp = hm % temp    
      if temp == 0: 
         prevtemp = temp 
         print("c: break") 
         break    
      while temp != 1 and temp != 0: 
         prevtemp = temp 
         temp = hm % temp 
    if temp == 0: 
      print("h: break") 
      break 
    y = Xploder(y) -offset 
  return hm, j, y.bit_length(), y, temp, prevtemp 



def build_prime_number(hm):
   si = 1
   for x in range(len(hm)):
     si = si * hm[x]
   return si

def Xploder(s, iter=1):
  return ((s+1) << (iter))-1


def powers(hm, y):
   return hm%y
```

Here is some speed test results from pollard brent compared to my optimizations ( for larger numbers, smaller numbers the random technique can be faster sometimes, but my optimizations consistently are on the lower bound, and i found much better results with larger factorizations ):

```
# Here get_factors_lars_opt calls my optimized version of y,c,m of pollard brent, and the get_factors_brent uses
# the original form with y,c,m as random

sin = 777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777

import time   
start = time.time()   
print(build_prime_number(get_factors_lars_opt(sin)))  
end = time.time()   
print("Time: ", end-start)                                                                                                                          
[3, 7, 7, 13, 11, 37, 103, 613, 4013, 210631, 2071723, 52986961, 21993833369, 5363222357, 291078844423, 13168164561429877, 377526955309799110357]
777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777
440.6862680912018


import time   
start = time.time()   
print(build_prime_number(get_factors_brent(sin)))  
end = time.time()   
print("Time: ", end-start)                                                                                                                          
[3, 7, 7, 13, 11, 37, 103, 613, 4013, 210631, 2071723, 52986961, 21993833369, 5363222357, 291078844423, 13168164561429877, 377526955309799110357]
777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777
Time:  814.3913190364838


sin = 272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727


import time   
start = time.time()   
print(build_prime_number(get_factors_lars_opt(sin))) 
end = time.time()   
print("Time: ", end-start)                                                                                                                                                                                                          

 [3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 13, 37, 103, 613, 4013, 210631, 2071723, 52986961, 5363222357, 21993833369, 291078844423, 13168164561429877, 377526955309799110357]
272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727
Time:  286.54595589637756

import time   
start = time.time()   
print(build_prime_number(get_factors_brent(sin))) 
end = time.time()   
print("Time: ", end-start)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 13, 37, 103, 613, 4013, 210631, 2071723, 5363222357, 52986961, 21993833369, 291078844423, 13168164561429877, 377526955309799110357]
272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727
Time:  833.4450578689575


sin =  6324591032675721961071009838204690217216135                                                                                                                                                                                        

import time  
start = time.time()  
print(build_prime_number(get_factors_lars_opt(sin,-2)))  
end = time.time()  
print(end-start)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

[5, 2267, 1031, 808309, 1034200481927, 647396143454755757]
6324591032675721961071009838204690217216135
3.2956199645996094

import time  
start = time.time()  
print(get_factors_brent(sin)) 
end = time.time()  
print(end-start)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[5, 2267, 1031, 808309, 1034200481927, 647396143454755757]
6.273381233215332

sin =  632459103267572196107100983820469021721613

import time  
start = time.time()  
print(build_prime_number(get_factors_lars_opt(sin,-2)))  
end = time.time() 
[3, 11, 11, 938861870237, 1855769878917004820751635923]
632459103267572196107100983820469021721613
0.9035940170288086

import time  
start = time.time()  
print(build_prime_number(get_factors_brent(sin,-2)))  
end = time.time() 
[3, 11, 11, 938861870237, 1855769878917004820751635923]
[3, 11, 11, 938861870237, 1855769878917004820751635923]
632459103267572196107100983820469021721613
6.698847055435181

import time   
start = time.time()   
print(get_factors_brent(sin))  
end = time.time()   
print(end-start)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
632459103267572196107100983820469021721613
[3, 11, 11, 938861870237, 1855769878917004820751635923]
1.687075138092041

# The point being that my optimizations always speed test to the lower end of the spectrum, when randomness can be as fast, faster or slower, so having my optimization leads to better consistently lower results. Anyway, this is to show that i'm interested in helping others optimize their techniques so hopefully a mathematician will help me optimize mine. Thx.
```

For questions regarding how this method works, you can use this code ( which i follow by examples of it finding the primes ). The issue with this pure method is that the squaring becomes slow as it reaches larger numbers. All primes are found by % mod of the number by it's bitslength powers of 2 offset by 2 and % modding down to you find a prime. You then divide by that prime and continue the processes. Once it's found all it's primes there, it squares the numbers and continues looking for it's bigger primes. Here is the code:

```
def SieveOfEratosthenes(n): 

    # Create a boolean array "prime[0..n]" and initialize 
    #  all entries it as true. A value in prime[i] will 
    # finally be false if i is Not a prime, else true. 
    prime = [True for i in range(n+1)] 
    p = 2
    while (p * p <= n): 

        # If prime[p] is not changed, then it is a prime 
        if (prime[p] == True): 

            # Update all multiples of p 
            for i in range(p * p, n+1, p): 
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1

    size = 0
    for p in range(2, n+1): 
      if prime[p]:
        size+=1

    vv = []
    count = 0 
    # Print all prime numbers 
    for p in range(2, n+1): 
        if prime[p]: 
            vv.append(p) 
            count+=1
    return vv


def get_factor_lars_prime(hm, offset=-2):
     num = hm
     vv = []
     a = lars_find_prime(num, offset)
     if a[5] == 0:
       vv.append(a[1])
     elif a[5] != 0 and a[3] == hm:
       vv.append(a[3])
     elif a[5] == 2:
       if num % 2 == 0:
         vv.append(a[5])
       else:
         vv.append(a[3])
     elif a[5] == 3:
       if num % 2 == 0:
          vv.append(2)
       elif num % 3 == 0:
          vv.append(3)
       elif num % 5 == 0:
          vv.append(5)
       elif num % a[3] == 0:
          vv.append(a[3])
     else:
       vv.append(a[5])
     num = num // vv[-1]
     return vv

def larsprimetest(hm):
   larstest = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
   primereducer = SieveOfEratosthenes(hm.bit_length())
   primetest = 0
   for x in primereducer:
     if hm == x:   
        return True
   for x in primereducer:
     if  pow(int(x),hm-1,hm)%hm != 1:   
        return False
   for x in larstest:
     if get_factor_lars_prime(hm, x)[0] == hm:
        primetest += 1
   if primetest == 5:
        return True
   else:
        return False
   return True


def get_factors(hm, offset=-2):
   num = hm
   vv = []
   while larsprimetest(num // 1) != True:
     print(vv, num)
     a = find_prime_evens(num, offset)
     print(a)
     if a[5] == 0:
       vv.append(a[1])
     elif a[5] != 0 and a[3] == hm:
       vv.append(a[3])
     elif a[5] == 2:
       if num % 2 == 0:
         vv.append(a[5])
       else:
         vv.append(a[3])
     elif a[5] == 3:
       if num % 2 == 0:
          vv.append(2)
       elif num % 3 == 0:
          vv.append(3)
       elif num % 5 == 0:
          vv.append(5)
       elif num % a[3] == 0:
          vv.append(a[3])
     else:
       vv.append(a[5])
     print(a)
     num = num // vv[-1]
   if larsprimetest(num):
     vv.append(num)
   print(vv)
   return vv

def Xploder(s, iter=1):
  return ((s+1) << (iter))-1


def powers(hm, y):
   return hm%y

def find_prime_evens(hm, offset=-2):
   y = 3
   prevtemp = 3
   if larsprimetest(hm):
      print(f"{hm} is already prime")
      return hm
   count = 0
   while True:
     count += 1
     if y.bit_length() > hm.bit_length() -1:
       hm = hm**2
     j = powers(hm, y)
     temp = j
     if j != 1 and j != 0:
       temp = j
       temp = hm % temp   
       if temp == 0:
          prevtemp = temp
          break   
       while temp != 1 and temp != 0:
          prevtemp = temp
          temp = hm % temp
     if temp == 0:
       print("h: break")
       break
     y = Xploder(y) -offset
   return hm, j, y.bit_length(), y, temp, prevtemp, count

def lars_find_prime(hm, offset=-2):
   y = 3
   prevtemp = 3 
   count = 0
   while True:
     count += 1
     j = powers(hm, y)
     temp = j
     if j != 1 and j != 0:
       temp = j
       temp = hm % temp   
       if temp == 0:
          prevtemp = temp
          break   
       while temp != 1 and temp != 0:
          prevtemp = temp
          temp = hm % temp
     if temp == 0:
       break
     y = Xploder(y) -offset
   return hm, j, y.bit_length(), y, temp, prevtemp, count


def build_prime_number(hm):
   si = 1
   for x in range(len(hm)):
     si = si * hm[x]
   return si

def lars_next_prime(hm):
   if hm == 1:
      return 2
   if hm == 2:
      return 3
   if hm % 2 == 0:
      hm = hm + 1
   hm += 2
   while larsprimetest(hm) == False:
      hm += 2
   return hm
```

Here are examples of it in action, i included extra prints so you can see it getting each prime in succession to help better understand how it works:

```
In [34]: build_prime_number(get_factors(1004))                                                                                                                                                                                             
[] 1004
(1004, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1)
(1004, 2, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1)
[2] 502
h: break
(502, 7, 4, 9, 0, 2, 2)
(502, 7, 4, 9, 0, 2, 2)
[2, 2, 251]
Out[34]: 1004

In [27]: get_factors(1009732533765202)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[] 1009732533765202
h: break
(1009732533765202, 16, 5, 21, 0, 2, 3)
(1009732533765202, 16, 5, 21, 0, 2, 3)
[2] 504866266882601
h: break
(504866266882601, 314, 9, 381, 0, 13, 7)
(504866266882601, 314, 9, 381, 0, 13, 7)
[2, 13] 38835866683277
h: break
(38835866683277, 22047719, 25, 25165821, 0, 373, 23)
(38835866683277, 22047719, 25, 25165821, 0, 373, 23)
[2, 13, 373] 104117605049
h: break
(10840475681139550292401, 66734543691418, 51, 1688849860263933, 0, 1097, 49)
(10840475681139550292401, 66734543691418, 51, 1688849860263933, 0, 1097, 49)
[2, 13, 373, 1097, 94911217]
Out[27]: [2, 13, 373, 1097, 94911217]

In [26]: get_factors(1009732533765203)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
[] 1009732533765203
h: break
(1009732533765203, 98408, 19, 393213, 0, 1823, 17)
(1009732533765203, 98408, 19, 393213, 0, 1823, 17)
[1823] 553885098061
h: break
(8858444060334285873499462093711776032199292767341903635560423388560603860385161070220665461281, 1837905802481463305694040153443073056866698693347558247643656, 202, 4820814132776970826625886277023487807566608981348378505904125, 0, 3163, 200)
(8858444060334285873499462093711776032199292767341903635560423388560603860385161070220665461281, 1837905802481463305694040153443073056866698693347558247643656, 202, 4820814132776970826625886277023487807566608981348378505904125, 0, 3163, 200)
[1823, 3163, 175113847]
Out[26]: [1823, 3163, 175113847]

In this example you can see what slows it down, the squaring results in a very large number making the number of % mods very high to find the resulting prime numbers:

In [35]: build_prime_number(get_factors(1009732533765211))                                                                                                                                                                                 
[] 1009732533765211
h: break
(1858687464945830613276207519418830078256252925527494817670836452584925872151997050342726690319815855916489163187476779328795581561584506918102376218558870556528131449536050119335272183001175087460816706604467590422729460305771026510195258807326149782536916059371245684962927048486207145468445983070111263743601945442437754692285582860831087579582865338897577976561107423651769237534542867346635933728009644016505419393349047377174870035612601951635799954836993221938911759004398692526370763278333555537149891691148929012230048164898839856174708241523484635142476852085507872602461333140057099374031231234692883772515864168322858763614749354444867119570513756048715083028301447984153569256687855399132439900591865090139158984073970060632974132395463497538996079103082850269708894436847549189253692504734313896341688057677128152397506215184070793063758319912367444161873329646621333822069513797521961617016648431755202336310221214445951592592865449312913586743041, 867432054263957195312394763826128523180839572794694625925893326576585472718884079259994297952068169500409139996557409526226130721935083932434155974396191513044409897151702362686457004179428822761911329822994774194886447878375861414059761388814088489690684480586657294595997373539633554633322628683970338029751517448126242789268931868877409296113419871613500698447737529174670292711688792459352329908009558736654555272729173099792228946045373872886607941401263166526198601410313477275934200380505058563197802581624185674924445556439949854181335354955193238910211915519483035004071046631189912140798111185601326587350356747504076298870161020037239314590660157491873623891581213042851417951748697766497038253143302123500968830751639348475147422594917068852946804447678119131167696912276272728600619979363485134551679606705258889428555149333805796401891036221772343868264049459632937898670649848299312252309046124292715358546940281583005313710132082, 3143, 10288158236705112447422412676734607870053121808427215392372356413249991433231817946259019960285051290857995822720743146217778185868842788207857017093380941762603675478415275610927176437914700447587292303826017744988440230377899747493402777461598453741291504123172281193487476681009866573741818827221076867067306582888054118228758213163000348022165104779211278807599015736046339741076053225413368146423933780513391217497933933021472551628227200656036586380577217835068596992642302384015703275756549655632282308707585597225290584296817091365296639633296475008816750266955889613824279377943214662329512838089193850285724935535928720351801544368420366013001495177810046104674236151184011707700353556483120087118410679668080153968024939929060725862159219354678155246920045922185882168329581212366120003846850432289454131135080189140814703595459255280289663654678483280428926392800140450176592552239268189492436400835156463000753657089320650379054022653, 0, 11344301, 3141)
(1858687464945830613276207519418830078256252925527494817670836452584925872151997050342726690319815855916489163187476779328795581561584506918102376218558870556528131449536050119335272183001175087460816706604467590422729460305771026510195258807326149782536916059371245684962927048486207145468445983070111263743601945442437754692285582860831087579582865338897577976561107423651769237534542867346635933728009644016505419393349047377174870035612601951635799954836993221938911759004398692526370763278333555537149891691148929012230048164898839856174708241523484635142476852085507872602461333140057099374031231234692883772515864168322858763614749354444867119570513756048715083028301447984153569256687855399132439900591865090139158984073970060632974132395463497538996079103082850269708894436847549189253692504734313896341688057677128152397506215184070793063758319912367444161873329646621333822069513797521961617016648431755202336310221214445951592592865449312913586743041, 867432054263957195312394763826128523180839572794694625925893326576585472718884079259994297952068169500409139996557409526226130721935083932434155974396191513044409897151702362686457004179428822761911329822994774194886447878375861414059761388814088489690684480586657294595997373539633554633322628683970338029751517448126242789268931868877409296113419871613500698447737529174670292711688792459352329908009558736654555272729173099792228946045373872886607941401263166526198601410313477275934200380505058563197802581624185674924445556439949854181335354955193238910211915519483035004071046631189912140798111185601326587350356747504076298870161020037239314590660157491873623891581213042851417951748697766497038253143302123500968830751639348475147422594917068852946804447678119131167696912276272728600619979363485134551679606705258889428555149333805796401891036221772343868264049459632937898670649848299312252309046124292715358546940281583005313710132082, 3143, 10288158236705112447422412676734607870053121808427215392372356413249991433231817946259019960285051290857995822720743146217778185868842788207857017093380941762603675478415275610927176437914700447587292303826017744988440230377899747493402777461598453741291504123172281193487476681009866573741818827221076867067306582888054118228758213163000348022165104779211278807599015736046339741076053225413368146423933780513391217497933933021472551628227200656036586380577217835068596992642302384015703275756549655632282308707585597225290584296817091365296639633296475008816750266955889613824279377943214662329512838089193850285724935535928720351801544368420366013001495177810046104674236151184011707700353556483120087118410679668080153968024939929060725862159219354678155246920045922185882168329581212366120003846850432289454131135080189140814703595459255280289663654678483280428926392800140450176592552239268189492436400835156463000753657089320650379054022653, 0, 11344301, 3141)
[11344301, 89007911]
Out[35]: 1009732533765211

You can use build_prime_number to prove the results

In [36]: build_prime_number([11344301, 89007911])                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[36]: 1009732533765211

You can also find the next prime with this:

In [2075]: lars_next_prime(1009732533765201)                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[2075]: 1009732533765251
```

Why i'm interested in this method and finding a shortcut to speed it up  is that the squaring can extract primes as such:

```
In [2076]: build_prime_number(get_factors(1009*1013))                                                                                                                                                                                      
[] 1022117
h: break
(1044723161689, 1046109004, 32, 4294967295, 0, 1013, 31)
(1044723161689, 1046109004, 32, 4294967295, 0, 1013, 31)
[1013, 1009]
Out[2076]: 1022117

In [2077]: build_prime_number(get_factors(100999*7187))                                                                                                                                                                                    
[] 725879813
h: break
(77075748221559656466333073070674906020465405143124137442807471435863521, 4486117980173565510874636581654887178239539699915726, 174, 23945242826029513411849172299223580994042798784118783, 0, 7187, 173)
(77075748221559656466333073070674906020465405143124137442807471435863521, 4486117980173565510874636581654887178239539699915726, 174, 23945242826029513411849172299223580994042798784118783, 0, 7187, 173)
[7187, 100999]
Out[2077]: 725879813
```

So a faster shortcut would be very beneficial.

Comment: I'm kind of slow, so it's not clear to me what your algorithm is, or whether it even works, let alone how to make it faster.

Comment: It works, the pollard_brent_lars_opt uses it and always comes up with the right answer, i haven't found any wrong ones. I also created a primality test with it that works as good as sympy. I'll be posting that to github soon and will post the link in the comments here. it includes an isprime and nextprime and from my testing, it works great.  I wish i could make it faster, i rely on the optimized pollard brent i created in conjunction with my lower bound prime finder to produce some of the fasted prime factorization speeds that i've ever seen, and better than any public library i've used

Comment: I'm not surprised it works sometime. Are you unable to explain why it works?

Comment: I can explain how it works. Primes of a number to the bitlength of a number are offset from the number & the it's powers of two of it's bitlength(-1)  offset by 2 mod down until the mod results in 0. You then have the prime.  The rest of the primes can be found by squaring the number and finding the primes there. Continue that process until all primes are found.  I'll post here shortly code that doesn't use brent_pollard so you can understand it more. My hope is to find someone to help me to speed it up. The only difference between mine and the above is that instead of squaring, i use bpollard

Comment: I'm still optimizing the code and will post to github soon.

Comment: Do you have any theoretical basis to expect this to be a useful way to search for factors? Is there any reason to expect this to work better than, say, trying candidate factors at random?

Comment: I've shown in the speed tests with the brent_pollard, that it's faster at finding factors than using a random y,c,m, by using the same offset from the powers of 2. So i think if we can find a way to speed it up by finding a shortcut ( which i am currently working on as well ) that it would be a very useful method. I just added at the bottom two examples of what i'm talking about, and you can see what slows it down. I have high hopes for it, and i will continue to look at it, but i'm also hoping to convince a mathematician that it could be very beneficial with a speed optimization.

Comment: "Less than a minute" to factorize 1009732533765211 is actually extremely slow. You can factorize that in [a second and a half](https://ideone.com/sv75oZ) with trial division, or [a tenth of a second](https://ideone.com/z5U1Mg) in C, and trial division is provably correct - if there is a factor, trial division will find it.

Comment: Exactly, which is why i was hoping that someone could help me find a speed optimization, i'm searching for one my self. I actually use brent_pollard with my optimization for now rather than the squaring. You can see from the speed results in that section that it's quite fast, and i'm sure faster than any method that's on the market unless you know of one that can factor those test numbers than with my changes. I think that's highly useful for those who factor numbers

Comment: The [quadratic sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve) is **much, much** faster than your algorithm, for example. I don't know why you're so sure that it's "faster than any method that's on the market" even in the face of test results showing it's slower than trial division, the simplest intro-to-CS factorization algorithm there is.

Comment: I'm talking about the pollard brent optimizations being faster. not mine. I would love to test it against a quadratic sieve algorithm, do you know of any libraries that utilize it to save me the time of writing one on my own? :-)

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could show me a method that factorizes this: 272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727 to  [3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 13, 37, 103, 613, 4013, 210631, 2071723, 52986961, 5363222357, 21993833369, 291078844423, 13168164561429877, 377526955309799110357] in less 
Time:  286.54595589637756  than that. That would give me something to study to help me optimize mine.

Comment: For pure Python, this is going to sound weird, but the best quadratic sieve implementation I'm aware of is [this answer on codegolf.stackexchange.com](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/fastest-semiprime-factorization/9088#9088).

Comment: There are also a few Github pages that come up in a search for `python quadratic sieve`, and a few PyPI projects that use an outdated, slightly buggy copy of the codegolf answer.

Comment: You second explanation of your algorithm is no clearer than your first. Perhaps tomorrow I'll go through it step by step. For fast, easy-to-use factoring, the best I've found is here: https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM. It factors 2727.... completely in 0.2 seconds.

Comment: The quadratic sieve is not a good choice for finding small factors of large numbers. For those the best algorithm is probably trial division up to a certain size, and then larger than that it's elliptic curve factoring. Their might be a very small window in which Pollard-rho and it's variants are fastest. The alpertron uses a combination of methods including elliptic curves and quadratic sieve.

Comment: One of the points i'd like to make is that in my section on the brent_pollard changes to use the different y,c,m's. IT is much faster than using random numbers.  I really do think this is a contribution worth looking at. I'm trying the mpqs algorithim now, and its taking longer than the optimization i made. So if anything, i hope to show that i did make an optimization that could be beneficial to mathematicians as i have really tried testing it against many libraries, including sympy, standard brent_pollard, and some others.

Comment: Since i can't find a library to factor faster than those brent_pollard y,c,m changes, it should be beneficial or helpful, and that's what i hope to get out of that part of the post. You don't have to use my hybrid, you can use it ( the y,c,m changes) straight up and see a substantial speed increase which i wanted to show. BTW, i'm using an older mac with 4 cores so those speeds should be much faster on newer machines

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  Yes. .ar is impressive, i would love to run there algorithims on my machine to test the speed differences on a normal Mac. But no doubt, two seconds is amazing. Where i can get that algorithim. If that exists and is as fast on my Mac, i want to research it and learn more about it

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk That .ar site factored 632459103267572196107100983820469021721602147490918660274601  in less than 10 seconds which i think is impossible on a normal machine. lol

Comment: @oppressionslayer: far from impossible. Using Pari/GP, `factorint(632459103267572196107100983820469021721602147490918660274601)` takes under 4 seconds on my not-particularly-high-powered laptop.

Comment: The software at alpertron.com.ar *is* running on your machine, specifically in your browser.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Duly noted. I'll try that out. i used https://github.com/skollmann/PyFactorise/blob/master/factorise.py with great results. At the end of the day though i was just hoping that someone may have known a cool mod technique to speed up what i was working on, because it's a cool project i was working on and just wanted to make it faster, not the fastest :-)